# Apply multiple functions to multiple columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to apply multiple functions to multiple columns of a `data.table`. Example:

```
DT <- data.table("a"=1:5,
                 "b"=2:6,
                 "c"=3:7)
```

Let's say I want to get the mean and the median of columns `a` and `b`.
This works:

```
stats <- DT[,.(mean_a=mean(a),
               median_a=median(a),
               mean_b=mean(b),
               median_b=median(b))]
```

But it is way too repetitive. Is there a nice way to achieve a similar result using `.SDcols` and `lapply`?

Comment: Why not put the functions into a custom function and call that?

Comment: Or, maybe look at the development version of "data.table" where `dcast` can handle multiple column aggregations at once.

Comment: This may be easier using `dplyr` `summarise_each(DT,funs(mean, median), 1:2)`

Comment: This'll be better when [`colwise()`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1063) is implemented.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'd normally do this:

```
my.summary = function(x) list(mean = mean(x), median = median(x))

DT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, my.summary)), .SDcols = c('a', 'b')]
#a.mean a.median   b.mean b.median 
#     3        3        4        4
```

Comment: I had a similar idea but thought the OP wanted a data.table output instead of a vector `DT[, as.list(unlist(lapply(.SD, my.summary))), .SDcols = c('a', 'b')]`

Comment: You could also probably simplify to `my.summary = function(x) c(mean = mean(x), median = median(x)) ; DT[, sapply(.SD, my.summary), .SDcols = a:b]`

Comment: But this seems to be awfully slow if I add a group by category
`DT[, as.list(unlist(lapply(.SD, my.summary))), 
        by=category,
        .SDcols=c('a', 'b') ]`

This is taking much longer than doing each summary individually and then joining. Any faster way to do this? I have about 1.5 million groups within the category column @akrun

Comment: Worth mentioning that the output is quite different (long) if adding  a `by` grouping! How would you do then?

Comment: I think the code with `by` would be: `as.list(unlist(lapply(...`?

Comment: @Matifou that works, but why the construct is `as.list(unlist(lapply(...`?

Comment: I think ideally, we would want a table that returns variables in rows and stats in columns. R's current `summary()` is far from readable, so this seems like a highly relevant problem to solve.

Comment: @altabq `melt`/`dcast` are your friends for that

Answer (score 16):

Other answers show how to do it, but no one bothered to explain the basic principle. The basic rule is that elements of lists returned by `j` expressions form the columns of the resulting `data.table`. Any `j` expression that produces a list, each element of which corresponds to a desired column in the result, will work. With this in mind we can use

```
DT[, c(mean = lapply(.SD, mean),
       median = lapply(.SD, median)),
  .SDcols = c('a', 'b')]
##    mean.a mean.b median.a median.b
## 1:      3      4        3        4
```

or

```
DT[, unlist(lapply(.SD,
                   function(x) list(mean = mean(x),
                                    median = median(x))),
            recursive = FALSE),
   .SDcols = c('a', 'b')]
##    a.mean a.median b.mean b.median
## 1:      3        3      4        4
```

depending on the desired order.

Importantly we can use any method we want to produce the desired result, provided only that we arrange the result into a list as described above. For example,

```
library(matrixStats)
DT[, c(mean = as.list(colMeans(.SD)),
       median = setNames(as.list(colMedians(as.matrix(.SD))), names(.SD))),
   .SDcols = c('a', 'b')]
##    mean.a mean.b median.a median.b
## 1:      3      4        3        4
```

also works.

Comment: I think the first example does not rename columns, but otherwise this was a very useful answer. Thanks!

Comment: Best answer that does not deviate from the principle. I've been always using `.()` for getting multiple outputs but combining this with lapply like `.(lapply(.SD), other = function(col) )` did not work well.  I realized using `c(lapply(.SD,func), other = function(col))` was the right approach.

Answer (score 11):

This is a little bit clumsy but does the job with `data.table`:

```
funcs = c('median', 'mean', 'sum')

m = DT[, lapply(.SD, function(u){
        sapply(funcs, function(f) do.call(f,list(u)))
     })][, t(.SD)]
colnames(m) = funcs

#  median mean sum
#a      3    3  15
#b      4    4  20
#c      5    5  25
```

Comment: Adding a new dependency just for one `t()` call seems to be a bit overhead, why not to use chaining? `m = DT[...][, t(.SD)]`. I think it is also more readable.

Comment: How to include a function that has an additional argument? Example: `quantile(., 0.25)`.

Comment: Use `Curry` from `functional` package and define `funcs = c(median, sum, Curry(quantile, probs=0.25))`. But you will have to define colnames yourself at this stage.

Answer (score 3):

use dcast

```
DT$dday <- 1 # add a constant column
dt <- dcast(DT, dday~dday, fun=list(sum, mean), value.var = c('a', 'b'))
# dday a_sum_1 b_sum_1 a_mean_1 b_mean_1
# 1      15      20        3        4
```

In fact, we can use dcast to implement onehot and feature engineer.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a little over-engineered, but if you come from dplyr's `summarize_at()` you might want to have a similar structured result.

First define a function `lapply_at()` which takes a `.SD` and a character vector of function names as inputs. Then you can easily compute your desired statistics and get a readable result.

```r
library(data.table)
iris_dt <- as.data.table(iris)

lapply_at <- function(var, funs, ...) {
  results <- sapply(var, function(var) {
    lapply(funs, do.call, list(var, ...))
  })
  names(results) <- vapply(names(var), paste, funs, sep = "_", 
                           FUN.VALUE = character(length(funs)),
                           USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  results
}

iris_dt[, lapply_at(.SD, c("mean", "sd"), na.rm = TRUE), 
        .SDcols = patterns("^Sepal"),
        by = Species]

#>       Species Sepal.Length_mean Sepal.Length_sd Sepal.Width_mean
#> 1:     setosa             5.006       0.3524897            3.428
#> 2: versicolor             5.936       0.5161711            2.770
#> 3:  virginica             6.588       0.6358796            2.974
#>    Sepal.Width_sd
#> 1:      0.3790644
#> 2:      0.3137983
#> 3:      0.3224966
```

Created on 2019-07-03 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).