# R data.table: mean for many columns

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to use the `data.table` package in `R` to calculate column means for many columns by another set of columns.  I know how to do this for a few columns, and I provide an example below.  However, in my non-toy example, I have tens of variables I would like to do this for, and I would like to find a way to do this from a vector of the column names.  Is this possible?

```
library(data.table)

# creates data table
dfo <- data.frame(bananas = 1:5, 
             melonas = 6:10,
             yeah = 11:15,
             its = c(1,1,1,2,2)
             )
dto <- data.table(dfo)

# gets column means by 'its' column
dto[,
.('bananas_mean' = mean(bananas),
  'melonas_mean' = mean(melonas),
  'yeah_mean' = mean(yeah)
  ),
by = .(its)]
```

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/q/16846380/ ?

Comment: Following up on Frank's comment, to get the naming the way you want you'd only need a slight modification: `cols <- c("bananas", "melonas", "yeah"); dto[,(paste0(cols, "_mean")) := lapply(.SD, mean), by = its, .SDcols = cols]`

Comment: I think there might be a problem with my `R`.  I tried that exact code, and I get no output.  Any idea why?

Comment: Well it's updating `dto` so have you tried looking at `dto` after you run it?

Comment: Oh that's very interesting.  It works!  I never saw `R` do this before.

Comment: @Frank How did you find that previously asked question?  I tried to do my due diligence before asking this question, but I didn't find it.

Comment: @BioBroo I clicked through my profile :) It's my answer there. Btw, you see no output since := updates by reference and so doesn't create a new object. You can add `[]` to the end of a data.table command to print the result, though.

Comment: Is there a way to set these new columns as a new object, rather than binding them to the old object?  I _could_ remove duplicates, but that seems pretty clunky.

Comment: This is stupidly simple in dplyr: `dfo %>% group_by(its) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean = mean))`

Comment: @alistaire Indeed.  Had I only been so enlightened at the time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
d <- dto[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=its]

d

   its bananas melonas yeah
1:   1     2.0     7.0 12.0
2:   2     4.5     9.5 14.5
```

Obviously, other functions could be used and combined. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 16):

The OP has requested *to calculate column means for many columns ... from a vector of the column names*. In addition, the OP has demonstrated in his sample code that he wants to rename the resulting columns.

Both the [excepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43815759/3817004) and the solution suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807631/r-data-table-mean-for-many-columns#comment74655101_43807631) *do not fully meet all* these requirements. The accepted answer computes means for *all* columns of the data.table and doesn't rename the results. The solution in the comments does use a vector of column names and renames the results but modifies the original data.table while [the OP expects a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807631/r-data-table-mean-for-many-columns#comment74667060_43807631).

The requirements of the OP can be met using the code below:

```
# define columns to compute mean of
cols <- c("bananas", "melonas")
# compute means for selected columns and rename the output
result <- dto[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = cols, by = its
              ][, setnames(.SD, cols, paste(cols, "mean", sep = "_"))]

result
#   its bananas_mean melonas_mean
#1:   1          2.0          7.0
#2:   2          4.5          9.5
```

Means are only computed for columns given as character vector of column names, the output columns have been renamed, and 
`dto` is unchanged.

**Edit** Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807631/r-data-table-mean-for-many-columns/43834005?noredirect=1#comment74705645_43834005) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29621821/3817004),
there is a way to make `data.table` rename the output columns *automagically*:

```
result <- dto[, sapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean = mean(x))), .SDcols = cols, by = its]
result
#   its bananas.mean melonas.mean
#1:   1          2.0          7.0
#2:   2          4.5          9.5
```

Comment: Could also do `f <- function(x) list(mean = mean(x)) ; dto[, sapply(.SD, f), .SDcols = cols]` or such. Or for multiple function it could be generalized to `f <- function(x) c(mean = mean(x), max = max(x)) ; dto[, sapply(.SD, f), .SDcols = cols]` or similar or even `f <- function(x) list(mean = mean(x), max = max(x)) ; dto[, unlist(lapply(.SD, f)), .SDcols = cols]`

Comment: It is taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620783/data-table-in-r-apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-columns/29621821#29621821) btw, which is probably a dupe target of this question

Comment: @DavidArenburg Unfortunately, the generalized version with multiple functions doesn't play nicely when combined with grouping

Comment: This is the best I could think of `f <- function(x, y) list(mean = mean(x), max = max(x)) ; dto[, setDT(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(.SD, f)), keep.rownames = TRUE), .SDcols = cols, by = its]`

Answer (score 1):

Adding an option using `colMeans`

```
dto[, as.list(colMeans(.SD)), by=its]
   its bananas melonas yeah
1:   1     2.0     7.0 12.0
2:   2     4.5     9.5 14.5
```

Choosing the columns by name

```
dto[, as.list(colMeans(.SD[, c("bananas", "melonas")])), by=its]
   its bananas melonas
1:   1     2.0     7.0
2:   2     4.5     9.5
```

or by range

```
dto[, as.list(colMeans(.SD[, 2:3])), by=its]
   its melonas yeah
1:   1     7.0 12.0
2:   2     9.5 14.5
```