# How to sum by group for all numeric vectors expect character vectors in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame which consists of numeric and character vectors for which i am trying to sum all vectors and divide it by 4, my code is as below

```
df2 =  df1%>%
  group_by(city,name,day,hour, age ,sex) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, function(x) sum(x/4,na.rm =T))
```

how can we write a same code in data.table package , so that we can save the time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Henrik,  how can we add sum/4 in mydt[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = cols]

Comment: You can pass an "anonymous function" to `lapply`, as described e.g. here: [data.table in R - apply multiple functions to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620783/data-table-in-r-apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-columns)