# Multiple functions on multiple columns by group, and create informative column names

Tags: r, data.table

How to adjust a data table manipulation so that, besides `sum` per category of several colums,
 it would also calculate other functions at the same time such as `mean` and counts (`.N`) and automatically create column names: "sum c1" , "sum c2", "sum c4" , "mean c1", " mean c2", "mean c4" and preferably also 1 column "counts"?

My old solution was to write out

```
mean col1 = ....
mean col2 = ....
```

Etc, Inside the data.table command

Which worked, but horribly inefficient I think, and it won't work anymore to precode it if in the new app version, the calculations depend on user choices in an R Shiny app what to calculate for which columns.

I've read my way through a bunch of posts and blog articles but haven't quite figured out how to best do this. I read that in some cases the manipulation can become quite slow on large data tables depending on what approach you use (.sdcols, get, lapply, and or by =). Therefore I added a 'sizeable' dummy data set

My real data is around 100k rows by 100 columns and 1-100 groups roughly.

```
library(data.table)
n = 100000
dt  = data.table(index=1:100000,
                 category = sample(letters[1:25], n, replace = T),
                 c1=rnorm(n,10000),
                 c2=rnorm(n,1000),
                 c3=rnorm(n,100),
                 c4 = rnorm(n,10)
)

# add more columns to test for big data tables 
lapply(c(paste('c', 5:100, sep ='')),
       function(addcol) dt[[addcol]] <<- rnorm(n,1000) )

# Simulate columns selected by shiny app user 

Colchoice <- c("c1", "c4")
FunChoice <- c(".N", "mean", "sum")

# attempt which now does just one function and doesn't add names
dt[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by=category, .SDcols=Colchoice ]
```

Expected output is a row per group and a column for each function per each selected column.

```
Category  Mean c1 Sum c1 Mean c4 ...
A
B
C
D
E
......
```

Possibly a duplicate but I haven't found the exact answer that I need

Comment: Guys, thanks for all the great answers and research. I'm away for Xmas at the moment and will try them out after those days immediately and accept one and give a bunch of upvotes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this question consists of two parts:

1. How to group and aggregate with multiple functions over a list of columns and generate new column names automatically.
2. How to pass the names of the functions as a character vector.

**For part 1**, this is *nearly* a duplicate of [Apply multiple functions to multiple columns in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29620783/3817004) but with the additional requirement that the results should be grouped using `by =`.

Therefore, [eddi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29621821/3817004) has to be modified by adding the parameter `recursive = FALSE` in the call to `unlist()`:

```
my.summary = function(x) list(N = length(x), mean = mean(x), median = median(x))
dt[, unlist(lapply(.SD, my.summary), recursive = FALSE), 
   .SDcols = ColChoice, by = category]
```

> ```
>     category c1.N   c1.mean c1.median c4.N   c4.mean c4.median
>  1:        f 3974  9999.987  9999.989 3974  9.994220  9.974125
>  2:        w 4033 10000.008  9999.991 4033 10.004261  9.986771
>  3:        n 4025  9999.981 10000.000 4025 10.003686  9.998259
>  4:        x 3975 10000.035 10000.019 3975 10.010448  9.995268
>  5:        k 3957 10000.019 10000.017 3957  9.991886 10.007873
>  6:        j 4027 10000.026 10000.023 4027 10.015663  9.998103
> ...
> ```

**For part 2**, we need to create `my.summary()` from a character vector of function names. This can be achieved by "*programming on the language*", i.e, by assembling an expression as character string and finally parsing and evaluating it:

```
my.summary <- 
  sapply(FunChoice, function(f) paste0(f, "(x)")) %>% 
  paste(collapse = ", ") %>% 
  sprintf("function(x) setNames(list(%s), FunChoice)", .) %>% 
  parse(text = .) %>% 
  eval()

my.summary
```

> ```
> function(x) setNames(list(length(x), mean(x), sum(x)), FunChoice)
> <environment: 0xe376640>
> ```

---

Alternatively, we can loop over the categories and `rbind()` the results afterwards:

```
library(magrittr)   # used only to improve readability
lapply(dt[, unique(category)],
       function(x) dt[category == x, 
                      c(.(category = x), unlist(lapply(.SD, my.summary))), 
                      .SDcols = ColChoice]) %>% 
  rbindlist()
```

---

#### Benchmark

So far, 4 `data.table` and one `dplyr` solutions have been posted. At least one of the answers claims to be "superfast". So, I wanted to verify by a benchmark with varying number of rows:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
bm <- bench::press(
  n = 10L^(2:6),
  {
    set.seed(12212018)
    dt <- data.table(
      index = 1:n,
      category = sample(letters[1:25], n, replace = T),
      c1 = rnorm(n, 10000),
      c2 = rnorm(n, 1000),
      c3 = rnorm(n, 100),
      c4 = rnorm(n, 10)
    )
    # use set() instead of <<- for appending additional columns
    for (i in 5:100) set(dt, , paste0("c", i), rnorm(n, 1000))
    tables()

    ColChoice <- c("c1", "c4")
    FunChoice <- c("length", "mean", "sum")
    my.summary <- function(x) list(length = length(x), mean = mean(x), sum = sum(x))
    
    bench::mark(
      unlist = {
        dt[, unlist(lapply(.SD, my.summary), recursive = FALSE),
           .SDcols = ColChoice, by = category]
      },
      loop_category = {
        lapply(dt[, unique(category)],
               function(x) dt[category == x, 
                              c(.(category = x), unlist(lapply(.SD, my.summary))), 
                              .SDcols = ColChoice]) %>% 
          rbindlist()
        },
      dcast = {
        dcast(dt, category ~ 1, fun = list(length, mean, sum), value.var = ColChoice)
        },
      loop_col = {
        lapply(ColChoice, function(col)
          dt[, setNames(lapply(FunChoice, function(f) get(f)(get(col))), 
                        paste0(col, "_", FunChoice)), 
             by=category]
        ) %>% 
          Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="category"), .)
      },
      dplyr = {
        dt %>% 
          dplyr::group_by(category) %>% 
          dplyr::summarise_at(dplyr::vars(ColChoice), .funs = setNames(FunChoice, FunChoice))
      },
      check = function(x, y) 
        all.equal(setDT(x)[order(category)], 
                  setDT(y)[order(category)] %>%  
                    setnames(stringr::str_replace(names(.), "_", ".")),
                  ignore.col.order = TRUE,
                  check.attributes = FALSE
                  )
    )  
  }
)
```

The results are easier to compare when plotted:

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

Please, note the logarithmic time scale.

For this test case, the *unlist* approach is always the fastest method, followed by *dcast*. *dplyr* is catching up for larger problem sizes `n`. Both *lapply/loop* approaches are less performant. In particular, [Parfait's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53886991/3817004) to loop over the columns and merge subresults afterwards seems to be rather sensitive to problem sizes `n`.

#### Edit: 2nd benchmark

As suggested by [jangorecki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53884353/multiple-functions-over-a-list-of-columns-and-generate-new-column-names-automati#comment94633009_53888852), I have repeated the benchmark with much more rows and also with a varying number of groups.
Due to memory limitations, the largest problem size is 10 M rows times 102 columns which takes 7.7 GBytes of memory.

So, the first part of the benchmark code is modified to

```
bm <- bench::press(
  n_grp = 10^(1:3),
  n_row = 10L^seq(3, 7, by = 2),
  {
    set.seed(12212018)
    dt <- data.table(
      index = 1:n_row,
      category = sample(n_grp, n_row, replace = TRUE),
      c1 = rnorm(n_row),
      c2 = rnorm(n_row),
      c3 = rnorm(n_row),
      c4 = rnorm(n_row, 10)
    )
    for (i in 5:100) set(dt, , paste0("c", i), rnorm(n_row, 1000))
    tables()
    ...
```

[image]

As expected by [jangorecki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53884353/multiple-functions-over-a-list-of-columns-and-generate-new-column-names-automati#comment94633009_53888852), some solutions are more sensitive to the number of groups than others. In particular, performance of *loop_category* is degrading much stronger with the number of groups while *dcast* seems to be less affected. For fewer groups, the *unlist* approach is always faster than *dcast* while for many groups `dcast` is faster. However, for larger problem sizes *unlist* seems to be ahead of *dcast*.

#### Edit 2019-03-12: *Computing on the language*, 3rd benchmark

Inspired by [this follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55098961/3817004), I have have added a *computing on the language* approach where the whole expression is created as character string, parsed and evaluated.

The expression is created by

```
library(magrittr)
ColChoice <- c("c1", "c4")
FunChoice <- c("length", "mean", "sum")
my.expression <- CJ(ColChoice, FunChoice, sorted = FALSE)[
  , sprintf("%s.%s = %s(%s)", V1, V2, V2, V1)] %>% 
  paste(collapse = ", ") %>% 
  sprintf("dt[, .(%s), by = category]", .) %>% 
  parse(text = .)
my.expression
```

> ```
> expression(dt[, .(c1.length = length(c1), c1.mean = mean(c1), c1.sum = sum(c1), 
>                   c4.length = length(c4), c4.mean = mean(c4), c4.sum = sum(c4)), by = category])
> ```

This is then evaluated by

```
eval(my.expression)
```

which yields

> ```
>     category c1.length   c1.mean   c1.sum c4.length   c4.mean   c4.sum
>  1:        f      3974  9999.987 39739947      3974  9.994220 39717.03
>  2:        w      4033 10000.008 40330032      4033 10.004261 40347.19
>  3:        n      4025  9999.981 40249924      4025 10.003686 40264.84
>  4:        x      3975 10000.035 39750141      3975 10.010448 39791.53
>  5:        k      3957 10000.019 39570074      3957  9.991886 39537.89
>  6:        j      4027 10000.026 40270106      4027 10.015663 40333.07
>  ...
> ```

I have modified the code of the 2nd benchmark to include this approach but had to reduce the additional columns from 100 to 25 in order to cope with the memory limitations of a much smaller PC. The chart shows that the "eval" approach is almost always the fastest or second:

[image]

Comment: Among all those presented plots there is only single measurement that took more than a second, you could consider scaling up it a little bit, something like `10^(1:4*2)`. Also you could scale data cardinality as it makes tremendous difference, see query1 and query5 on this groupby benchmark: https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/

Comment: `.N` is a special symbol of the `data.table` package and it is only available if this package has been loaded properly.

Comment: found out what the problem was with the .N. Didn't see that you changed the list of functions to 'lenght', got it working now. I'll probably end up using the dcast solution. Thanks for all the testing and research Uwe! very educative answer for sure

Comment: Uwe, I've posted a follow up with another level of complication to it. It can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098961/r-shiny-custom-statistic-selection-how-to-calculate-different-statistics-to-dif

Answer (score 6):

Here's a data.table answer:

```
funs_list <- lapply(FunChoice, as.symbol)
dcast(dt, category~1, fun=eval(funs_list), value.var = Colchoice)
```

It's super fast and does what you want.

Comment: This is oh so elegant data.table way to solve, not sure why you say almost. If you want to pass in the strings like you would in Shiny you can do this: `FunChoice <- c("sum", "mean")
funs_list <- lapply(FunChoice, as.symbol)
dcast(dt, category~1, fun=eval(funs_list), value.var = Colchoice)`

Answer (score 1):

Consider building a list of data tables where you iterate through every *ColChoice* and apply each function of *FuncChoice* (setting names accordingly). Then, to merge all data tables together, run `merge` in a `Reduce` call. Also, use `get` to retrieve environment objects (functions/columns).

**Note**: *ColChoice* was renamed for camel case and `length` function replaces `.N` for functional form for count:

```
set.seed(12212018)  # RUN BEFORE data.table() BUILD TO REPRODUCE OUTPUT
...

ColChoice <- c("c1", "c4")
FunChoice <- c("length", "mean", "sum")

output <- lapply(ColChoice, function(col)
                   dt[, setNames(lapply(FunChoice, function(f) get(f)(get(col))), 
                                 paste0(col, "_", FunChoice)), 
                      by=category]
          )

final_dt <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="category"), output)

head(final_dt)

#    category c1_length   c1_mean   c1_sum c4_length   c4_mean   c4_sum
# 1:        a      3893 10000.001 38930003      3893  9.990517 38893.08
# 2:        b      4021 10000.028 40210113      4021  9.977178 40118.23
# 3:        c      3931 10000.008 39310030      3931  9.996538 39296.39
# 4:        d      3954 10000.010 39540038      3954 10.004578 39558.10
# 5:        e      4016  9999.998 40159992      4016 10.002131 40168.56
# 6:        f      3974  9999.987 39739947      3974  9.994220 39717.03
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's not a straightforward answer using data.table since noone has answered this yet. So I'll propose a dplyr-based answer that should do what you want. I use the built-in iris data set for the example:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width), .funs = c(sum=sum,mean= mean), na.rm=TRUE)

## A tibble: 3 x 5
#  Species    Sepal.Length_sum Sepal.Width_sum Sepal.Length_mean Sepal.Width_mean
#  <fct>                 <dbl>           <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>
#1 setosa                 245.            171.              5.00             3.43
#2 versicolor             297.            138.              5.94             2.77
#3 virginica              323.            149.              6.60             2.97
```

or using character vector input for the columns and functions:

```
Colchoice <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
FunChoice <- c("mean", "sum")
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Colchoice), .funs = setNames(FunChoice, FunChoice), na.rm=TRUE)
## A tibble: 3 x 5
#  Species    Sepal.Length_mean Sepal.Width_mean Sepal.Length_sum Sepal.Width_sum
#  <fct>                  <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>
#1 setosa                  5.00             3.43             245.            171.
#2 versicolor              5.94             2.77             297.            138.
#3 virginica               6.60             2.97             323.            149.
```

Comment: nice, just could not figure out how to also count 'length' or '.N' in this. 'length' gives an error '2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires one'

Answer (score 0):

If the summary statistics you need to compute are things like `mean`, `.N`, and (perhaps) `median`, which `data.table` optimizes into c code across the by, you may have faster performance if you convert the table into long form so that you can do the computations in a way that data table can optimize them:

```
> library(data.table)
> n = 100000
> dt  = data.table(index=1:100000,
                   category = sample(letters[1:25], n, replace = T),
                   c1=rnorm(n,10000),
                   c2=rnorm(n,1000),
                   c3=rnorm(n,100),
                   c4 = rnorm(n,10)
  )
> {lapply(c(paste('c', 5:100, sep ='')), function(addcol) dt[[addcol]] <<- rnorm(n,1000) ); dt}

> Colchoice <- c("c1", "c4")

> dt[, .SD
     ][, c('index', 'category', Colchoice), with=F
     ][, melt(.SD, id.vars=c('index', 'category'))
     ][, mean := mean(value), .(category, variable)
     ][, median := median(value), .(category, variable)
     ][, N := .N, .(category, variable)
     ][, value := NULL
     ][, index := NULL
     ][, unique(.SD)
     ][, dcast(.SD, category ~ variable, value.var=c('mean', 'median', 'N') 
     ]

    category mean_c1 mean_c4 median_c1 median_c4 N_c1 N_c4
 1:        a   10000  10.021     10000    10.041 4128 4128
 2:        b   10000  10.012     10000    10.003 3942 3942
 3:        c   10000  10.005     10000     9.999 3926 3926
 4:        d   10000  10.002     10000    10.007 4046 4046
 5:        e   10000   9.974     10000     9.993 4037 4037
 6:        f   10000  10.025     10000    10.015 4009 4009
 7:        g   10000   9.994     10000     9.998 4012 4012
 8:        h   10000  10.007     10000     9.986 3950 3950
...
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't really see how this does what OP asked for since they wanted to supply two vectors, one with column names and another with function names. In your example, you just manually compute mean, median etc. Plus, I'm not sure why your first step is `dt[, .SD]` (which seems unnecessary) and then `dt[, ..., with=FALSE]` which is also not necessary and probably makes a deep copy. Your general idea of reshaping to long format may be good, though.

Comment: Yep this doesn't handle the requirement to provide a vector of functions as text. I didn't see a clean way to do that in long form and figured that that's likely the least likely of the 2 vectors that needs to be programatic. The `dt[, SD]` as the first row in the pipeline and the `..., with=FALSE` are choices for better readability.

Comment: The code works (apart from missing closing bracket at the end ), but it seems to over-complicate things more than the code I already had and indeed as mentioned doesn't meet my needs of both functions and columns coming from text string