# Different functions over a list of columns and generate new column names automatically with data.table

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I have a section in my Shiny app that generates a list.

names of the list are column names of the `dataframe` we will calculate on,
list items contain the calculations we want

Looking to do this:
`apply` to all `list` names:
for `listname` (`column`) x calculate `function` `n,m,o` over `df column` x
and name the resulting column '`x.n`' i.e. '`cyl.mean'`, '`mpg.sum`'
to get a `dataframe` of summary statistics PER GROUP (mtcars$cyl) in this case as example

It is linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53884353/multiple-functions-over-a-list-of-columns-and-generate-new-column-names-automati) question, but there the example `data` used a separate `list` of `column` names, and `apply` the same `functions` to all those `columns` from another `list`. I'm looking to move forward to `apply` `unique` sets of `functions` to different `columns`

The list my app spits out looks like this:

```
mylist


$disp
[1] "sum"  "mean"

$hp
[1] "sd"

$drat
[1] "sum"  "mean"

$wt
[1] "max"
```

expected output:

```
cyl    disp.sum  hp.sd  drat.sum  drat.mean wt.max    
4        x ....  
6        x ....  
8        x  ....
```

The little Shiny app to create the list:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(shinyjs)

Channels <- names(mtcars)[3:8]

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  h5('Channels', style = 'font-weight:bold'),
  uiOutput('ChannelCheckboxes'),
  h5('Statistics', style = 'font-weight:bold'),
  uiOutput('CalculationCheckboxes')

)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues(Statisticlist = list())
  ## build observer to deselect all sub category checkboxes if channel is deselected
  lapply(Channels, function(x) {
    observeEvent(input[[paste('Channel', x, sep = '')]], {
      if(!input[[paste('Channel', x, sep = '')]]) {
        shinyjs::disable(paste("Calculations", x, sep = ''))
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = paste("Calculations", x, sep = ''), selected=character(0))

      } else {
        shinyjs::enable(paste("Calculations", x, sep = ''))

        }
    })
  })

  output$ChannelCheckboxes <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
    lapply(Channels, function(x) {
      column(2,
             checkboxInput(inputId = paste('Channel', x, sep = ''), label = x)
        )
    })
  )
  })

output$CalculationCheckboxes <- renderUI({
  fluidRow(
    lapply(Channels, function(x) {
      column(2,
             checkboxGroupInput(inputId = paste("Calculations", x, sep = ''),  label = NULL, c('sum', 'mean', 'length', 'max', 'min', 'sd')) ) })
  )
})


  lapply(Channels, function(x) {
    observe({
      req(input[[paste('Channel', x, sep = '')]])
      if(input[[paste('Channel', x, sep = '')]] & !is.null(input[[paste("Calculations", x, sep = '')]])){
     values$Statisticlist[[paste(x)]] <- input[[paste("Calculations", x, sep = "")]]

      }
    })
  })


  observeEvent(values$Statisticlist, { print(values$Statisticlist)
    mylist <<- values$Statisticlist
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the question is not about [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) in first place but about how to apply different aggregation functions to specific columns of a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table).

The names of the columns and the functions which are to be applied on are given as list `mylist` which is created by the shiny app.

Among the various approaches my preferred option is to *compute on the language*, i.e., to create a complete expression from the contents of `mylist` and to evaluate it:

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
mylist %>%
  names() %>% 
  lapply(
    function(.col) lapply(
      mylist[[.col]], 
      function(.fct) sprintf("%s.%s = %s(%s)", .col, .fct, .fct, .col))) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  paste(collapse = ", ") %>% 
  sprintf("as.data.table(mtcars)[, .(%s), by = cyl]", .) %>% 
  parse(text = .) %>% 
  eval()
```

which yields the expected result

> ```
>    cyl disp.sum disp.mean    hp.sd drat.sum drat.mean wt.max
> 1:   6   1283.2  183.3143 24.26049    25.10  3.585714  3.460
> 2:   4   1156.5  105.1364 20.93453    44.78  4.070909  3.190
> 3:   8   4943.4  353.1000 50.97689    45.21  3.229286  5.424
> ```

The character string which is parsed is created by

```
mylist %>%
  names() %>% 
  lapply(
    function(.col) lapply(
      mylist[[.col]], 
      function(.fct) sprintf("%s.%s = %s(%s)", .col, .fct, .fct, .col))) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  paste(collapse = ", ") %>% 
  sprintf("as.data.table(mtcars)[, .(%s), by = cyl]", .)
```

and looks as if coded manually:

> ```
> [1] "as.data.table(mtcars)[, .(disp.sum = sum(disp), disp.mean = mean(disp), hp.sd = sd(hp), drat.sum = sum(drat), drat.mean = mean(drat), wt.max = max(wt)), by = cyl]"
> ```

#### Data

For demonstration, `mylist` is provided "hard-coded":

```
mylist <- list(
  disp = c("sum", "mean"),
  hp = "sd",
  drat = c("sum", "mean"),
  wt = "max")
```

Comment: Hi Uwe, thanks for your answer! this is indeed what I was trying to build. Now trying to build it into my real App. One small follow-up question, would it be possible to turn the mylist %>% ... into a function? I'm looking to change the syntax so that mylist, mtcars and 'cyl' are replaced by input arguments like: 
MySummary <- function(statisticslist, dataframe, grouping) { statisticslist %>%..... etc }  but not sure how that works for the sprintf line

Comment: Ah, seems that was easier than I thought.

Comment: @Mark. Great, you solved it your own. `sprintf()` seems not be as popular as `paste()` although it has advantages in cases like this one. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Uwe, I would like to add my own functions like count, concentration and percentage to the list. For count I just add 'length' to the mylist$ID (the first column in my data, for percentage however  I would like to divide group length by dataframe nrow, but I get errors that dataframe is not found. 
This is my formula attempt: Percentage <- function(x){
        (length(x)/nrow(deparse(substitute(dataframe))))*100
    }

Comment: @Mark, I was tempted to give a quick answer suggesting to define the function beforehand and include the name in `mylist` but I may miss your point. Computing on the language is pretty advanced stuff in R (at least for me). It is difficult for me to answer without the complete context. Therefore, I suggest that you post a new question, please.

Comment: that's exactly what I tried to do, but I don't know how to access the number of rows of the entire dataframe within your answer. i.e. to get the function Percentage I define before hand divide the length of the group by the nrow of the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

To turn Uwe's answer into a function I did this:

```
Summarystats <- function(statlist, dataframe, group) { 
    statlist %>%
        names() %>% 
        lapply(
            function(.col) lapply(
                statlist[[.col]], 
                function(.fct) sprintf("%s.%s = %s(%s)", .col, .fct, .fct, .col))) %>% 
        unlist() %>% 
        paste(collapse = ", ") %>% 
        sprintf("as.data.table(dataframe)[, .(%s), by = group]", .) %>% 
        parse(text = .) %>% 
        eval()
    }
```

Now I can call:

```
Summarystats(mylist, mtcars, 'cyl')
```

allowing me to call a summary table for whichever dataframe and grouping the user wants in my Shiny App.