# What is the equivalent of mutate_at (dplyr) in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I am trying to move some of my slower processes in dplyr to using data.table, however can not seem to find an efficient way of using a "mutate_at" type approach in data.table. Especially, when it comes to naming the new variables created & applying more than 1 function to multiple columns.

Below I use mutate_at to apply 2 different functions to 2 different columns with associated naming + using a group by statement. I want to be able to replicate this easily in data.table.

```
library(tibble)
library(zoo)

Data = tibble(A = rep(c(1,2),50),
              B = 1:100,
              C = 101:200)

Data %>% 
    group_by(A) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(B,C), funs(Roll.Mean.Week = 7 * rollapply(., width = 7, mean, align = "right", fill = 0, na.rm = T, partial = T),
                              Roll.Mean.Two.Week = 7 * rollapply(., width = 14, mean, align = "right", fill = 0, na.rm = T, partial = T))) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through the `.SD` with `lapply` and apply the function of interest.  Here, the funcion `rollapply` is repeated with only change in `width` parameter.  So, it may be better to create a function to avoid repeating the whole arguments.  Also, while applying the function (`f1`), the output can be kept in a `list`, later `unlist` with `recursive = FALSE` and assign (`:=`) to columns of interest

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
nm1 <- c("B", "C")
nm2 <- paste0(nm1, "_Roll.Mean.Week")
nm3 <- paste0(nm1, "_Roll.Mean.Two.Week")
f1 <- function(x, width) rollapply(x, width = width, mean,
        align = "right", fill = 0, na.rm = TRUE, partial = TRUE)
setDT(Data)[, c(nm2, nm3) := unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x)
  list(f1(x, 7), f1(x, 14))), recursive = FALSE), by = A, .SDcols = nm1]
head(Data)
#   A B   C B_Roll.Mean.Week C_Roll.Mean.Week B_Roll.Mean.Two.Week C_Roll.Mean.Two.Week
#1: 1 1 101                1                1                  101                  101
#2: 2 2 102                2                2                  102                  102
#3: 1 3 103                2                2                  102                  102
#4: 2 4 104                3                3                  103                  103
#5: 1 5 105                3                3                  103                  103
#6: 2 6 106                4                4                  104                  104
```

---

Note that `funs` is deprecated in `tidyverse` and in its place, can use `list(~` or just `~`

```
Data %>% 
    group_by(A) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(B,C), list(Roll.Mean.Week =  ~f1(., 7),
                              Roll.Mean.Two.Week = ~ f1(., 14)))%>% 
    ungroup()
```

Comment: This solution does not satisfy the request to have the new column names added to the original tibble, as mutate_at does. Noted regarding the deprecated funs.

Comment: @JackFahey-Gilmour.  For that it is just `:=` (updated the answer)

Comment: what about the ability to easily apply two function calls to the same set of variables, as specified above.

Comment: @JackFahey-Gilmour. Have you checked my update.  I thought it is the same repeating stuff, so I didn't earlier update

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid multiple chains? Or do you have to keep chaining the functions in seperate calls?

Comment: @JackFahey-Gilmour. You can do it single chain itself, but it is more clear this way

Comment: Is it possible to provide both solutions? I think that would provide a well rounded answer.

Comment: @JackFahey-Gilmour. Updated the answer

Comment: I just realised that the allocation of column names is not in order. It should be, B_Roll.Mean.Week, B_Roll.Mean.Two.Week, C_Roll.Mean.Week, C_Roll.Mean.Two.Week

Comment: @JackFahey-Gilmour. You can change the order with `setcolorder(Data, yourorder)`

Answer (score 1):

And also from [Apply multiple functions to multiple columns in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620783/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-columns-in-data-table/29621821#29621821)

```
f <- function(x) lapply(c(Roll.Mean.Week=7L, Roll.Mean.Two.Week=14L),
    function(n) rollapplyr(x, width=n, mean, fill=0L, na.rm=TRUE, partial=TRUE))
DT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, f), recursive=FALSE), A, .SDcols=B:C]
```

output:

```
     A B._Roll.Mean.Week B._Roll.Mean.Two.Week C._Roll.Mean.Week C._Roll.Mean.Two.Week
  1: 1                 1                     1               101                   101
  2: 1                 2                     2               102                   102
  3: 1                 3                     3               103                   103
  4: 1                 4                     4               104                   104
  5: 1                 5                     5               105                   105
  6: 1                 6                     6               106                   106
  7: 1                 7                     7               107                   107
  8: 1                 9                     8               109                   108
  9: 1                11                     9               111                   109
 10: 1                13                    10               113                   110
 [trunc...]
```