# mutate_at (dplyr) alternative in data.table for converting dates

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I had the following code to change all columns starting with "DT" to `Date` format with `mutate_at` from `dplyr`

```
date_cols <- str_subset(names(df),'^DT')
df <- df %>%
  mutate_at(
    .vars= date_cols,
    .funs=list(~ as.Date(.,format = "%d%m%Y"))
  )
```

To do the same thing using data.table I wrote the following code (which works)

```
date_cols <- str_subset(names(df),'^DT')
for (column in date_cols) {
  df[,(column) := as.Date(df[[..column]],format = "%d%m%Y")]
}
```

The question is if there isn't a `mutate_at` equivalent in `data.table` which would avoid the explicit `for` loop? (Not really a problem, just curiosity)

Comment: [How to apply same function to every specified column in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846380/how-to-apply-same-function-to-every-specified-column-in-a-data-table)

Comment: Thank @countorlok, simplifying the answer from that post a bit I was able to do it

Answer (score 1):

Based on a more complex answer from [What is the equivalent of mutate_at (dplyr) in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386580/what-is-the-equivalent-of-mutate-at-dplyr-in-data-table) indicated by count orlok, I wrote the following code which works as I wanted

```
date_cols <- str_subset(names(df),'^DT')
df[,(date_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.Date(x,format = "%d%m%Y")), 
   .SDcols = date_cols]
```